# Unable to deploy Dash App within Flask App using gunicorn: gunicorn vs flask run

Tags: python, flask, plotly-dash, gunicorn, gevent

I am trying to deploy a dashapp as a page within my flask application, using gunicorn. My setup works just fine when running flask in development mode, but when I run the application using gunicorn I am unable to access the dashboard section.

This is the how my app is organized:

dashapp/
-- assets/
-- layout.py
-- callbacks.py

entities/
-- entity.py

main.py
gunicorn_config.py

In the layout and callbacks, I define the proper layout and callbacks for my dashapp. In the script **main.py** is where I bind my dashapp to the flask app by doing:

**main.py**

```py
from entities.entity app
import argparse
import dash
from dashapp.layout import get_layout
from dashapp.callbacks import register_callbacks
from distutils.util import strtobool
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, Blueprint, session
from flask_cors import CORS
import flask_excel as excel
from flask_jwt_extended import jwt_required
from flask_mail import Message
from flask.helpers import get_root_path
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer


env = os.getenv('env', 'dev').lower()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # INITIALIZE ON DASH. THEN RUN THE DASH APP
    meta_viewport = {
        "name": "viewport",
        "content": "width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    }
    dashapp = dash.Dash(__name__,
                        server=app,
                        url_base_pathname='/dashboards/',
                        assets_folder=get_root_path(__name__) + '/dashboards/assets/',
                        meta_tags=[meta_viewport])

    with app.app_context():
        dashapp.title = 'Dashapp 1'
        dashapp.layout = get_layout()
        register_callbacks(dashapp)

    if env == 'dev':
        # Args parser
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='InSkin Arguments')
        parser.add_argument('-f', '--host', type=str, nargs='?', help='API Host')
        parser.add_argument('-p', '--port', type=int, nargs='?', help='API Port')
        parser.add_argument('-c', '--cert', type=str, nargs='?', help='Certificate File: cert.pem')
        parser.add_argument('-k', '--key', type=str, nargs='?', help='Key File: key.pem')
        parser.add_argument('-d', '--debug', type=lambda x: bool(strtobool(x)), nargs='?', help='API Debug Mode')
        parser.print_help()
        args = parser.parse_args()

        api_host = args.host if args.host else get_value_from_config(PROJECT_FILE, PROJECT_SECTION, 'flask_host')
        api_port = args.port if args.port else get_value_from_config(PROJECT_FILE, PROJECT_SECTION, 'flask_port')
        certfile = args.cert
        keyfile = args.key
        api_debug = args.debug if args.debug else get_value_from_config(PROJECT_FILE, PROJECT_SECTION, 'flask_debug',
                                                                        is_boolean=True,
                                                                        required=False)
        assert (certfile is not None and keyfile is not None) or (certfile is None and keyfile is None), \
            'Certfile and Keyfile must either be both provided or None be provided. You only provided one of the two, ' \
            'please add the other or remove both'

        if certfile:
            ssl_context = (certfile, keyfile)
            app.run(host=api_host, port=api_port, debug=api_debug, ssl_context=ssl_context)
        else:
            app.run(host=api_host, port=api_port, debug=api_debug)
    else:
        app.run()
```

As you can see, I use an environment variable to decide whether to run the app in development mode, with some arguments that I select from command line. This works fine and shows the dashapp in the */dashboards* url of my app when I run it using the comand:

```bash
python3 main.py --host=0.0.0.0 --port=5001 --cert=cert.pem --key=key.pem
```

However, if I try to run it using gunicorn:

```bash
gunicorn -c gunicorn_config.py main:app
```

then the dashapp section is unavailable and returns a 404 error. The rest of the application works just fine, it seems that what is lost is the link between my flask app and the dash app. Here is the gunicorn_cofig.py file:

```py
certfile = 'cert.pem'
keyfile = 'key.pem'
bind = '0.0.0.0:5001'
workers = 3
worker_class = 'gevent'
errorlog = '../logs/errorlog.log'
log_file = '../logs/log.log'
loglevel = 'debug'
accesslog = '../logs/accesslog.log'
access_log_format = '%(h)s %(l)s %(u)s %(t)s "%(r)s" %(s)s %(b)s "%(f)s" "%(a)s"'
worker_connections = 100
raw_env = [
    'debug=true',
    'env=pre',
]
```

Another option that I was contemplating was to use the ***gevent.pyWSGI WSGIServer*** class. The problem here is that I have been unable to change the number of workers used by default by my application. I would like to increase workers and threads in order to be able to server multiple requests at the same time, since I am expecting a high load on my app in the next weeks.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank you so much!